# proof about sigma-algebra

Tags: probability, analysis

The question is that, $f$ is a function mapping $\Omega$ to another space $E$ with a $\sigma$-algebra $\varepsilon$.
Let $\mathbf{A}= \{A\subset\Omega : \text{there exists } B \in \varepsilon \text{ with }\ A=f^{-1}(B)\}$.
Show that $\mathbf{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$.

My idea is that, first I need to prove that $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ are both in $\mathbf{A}$. But is it sufficient to claim that $f^{-1}(\emptyset_{E})=\emptyset_{\Omega}$ and $f^{-1}(E)=\Omega$?

Next, to prove that $\mathbf{A}$ is closed under complementation and countable unions, is it okay to do like $A=f^{-1}(B)$, then $A^{c}=[f^{-1}(B)]^c$ and thus $B^{c} \in E\rightarrow A^{c}\in \mathbf{A}$

$A_{i}\in \mathbf{A}, A_{i}=f^{-1}(B_{i}),\bigcup ^{\infty}_{i=1}A_{i}=\bigcup ^{\infty}_{i=1}f^{-1}(B_{i}) =f^{-1}(\bigcup ^{\infty}_{i=1}B_{i})\rightarrow\bigcup ^{\infty}_{i=1}A_{i}\in \mathbf{A}$?

I do think this is intuitive but feel it somehow weird because there is not any property on $f$ that has been given other than it is invertible. 
Could anyone help?

Comment: Is that $\Phi$ supposed to be an $\emptyset$?

Comment: You didn't even use the fact that $f$ is invertible and infact most of the time it will not be.

Comment: yes it is an empty set! it is corrected now:)thanks a lot

Comment: ah...I think there should be some argument that makes it possible for me to switch the unions and $f^{-1}$ but not yet know how to...

Comment: Preimages and unions do commute in general (infact, unions and forward images commute).

Answer (score 0):

$f^{-1}(B)$ refers to the points that get mapped by $f$ into $B$. $f^{-1}(B)$ is meaningful whenever $f$ is well-defined and doesn't require that $f$ has an inverse.

$A$ (also known as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $f$) is a $\sigma$-algebra because of these facts:

- $[f^{-1}(B)]^c=f^{-1}(B^c)$,
- $\cup_if^{-1}(B_i)=f^{-1}(\cup_i B_i)$.

Both are correct and can be verified, say, by showing $\text{LHS}\subset\text{RHS}$ and $\text{RHS}\subset\text{LHS}$  (although you misused (mistyped) the first one slightly).

Comment: thanks a lot! I will correct it!